# Inserting and Ammending Text in ini file in CHEF

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've just started using CHEF at work and I've been asked to download a package to a Linux host, unpack it, apply the license and start it.

As part of the unpack an ini file is created that should contain the license info. The license file itself is the same as the ini files [license] section but it also contains further detail in other sections.

What I would like to do is search the ini file for license block then insert the detail from the license file in to it.

So the ini file looks something like this initially

```
[Licence]
;You have to complete this section to start

[users]
admin=admin

[roles]
admin = admin, operate, user

[modules]
```

My license file would be like this

```
[licence]
Serial=123456789
baa=3 bags full
Key=123456789
ExpireDate=2016-06-10 00-00-00r
```

I don't know the best way to do this in CHEF. I've got a couple of questions

1. Should I use a template with values and create it in my recipe?
2. Can I do it using Ruby and how would I get that into my recipe?
3. How do I check the line exists already and make sure I don't overwrite it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is in Chef is to manage the entire file, and use a [template resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html). If you really want to try your 2nd or 3rd bullet points,  check out the [line cookbook](https://github.com/someara/line-cookbook) for some examples of file editing in-place (and using `not_if` to guard against appending lines twice).

To re-iterate, though -- manage the whole file with chef using a template. That's the most idiomatic way to do this in Chef.